# API desing – Is it ok to fetch user's data from auth token?

Tags: authentication, token, api-design

Let's consider this use case:

1) I call my API login endpoint with username and password and get my Auth token that I add to every consecutive request to the header as `Authorization: Bearer <token>`.

2) I call `/current-user` endpoint with no params, only with Authorization header. Server authorizes user using token and gets user's id from that token. Then he finds the user by id in database and returns it's data.

**My question is, whether this approach isn't insecure.** I'm wondering, what if I was an attacker and was calling `/current-user` endpoint using randomly generated tokens. Once I occasionally matched real token, the server would return me other user's data.

Isn't it necessary to store user id on client along with token and call requests using both? Eg. `/user?id=<stored user id>` with Authorization header and get rid of `/current-user` endpoint? After that some kind of ACL on server would determine, whether used token has allowed access to user with passed user id.

(I also found there are JWT tokens but I see the same problem there. As an attacker I would somehow manage to guess other user's token and server would return me his data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security purposes, it is normally assumed that the user id is known to the attacker anyway. For example, if the attacker already has or knows a legitimate account, she might be able to guess how other user ids are assigned.

Also, if your token is long enough and totally random, it doesn't really make any difference.

Look at it this way: let's say your token has length `n`, your user id has length `m`. Without the user id, the attacker has to guess `n` characters, with it included she has to guess `n+m` characters. If your `n` is high enough, you don't need those extra characters. Keep in mind that the *effective* length of the user id might be much shorter than its apparent length if your user ids aren't completely random, so the `m` added might actually be really small.

Comment: Hm hm I get it. So I basically make the token long enough. BTW: It won't be `n+m` but more because he has to guess the combination I think (?)

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible for you to use digitally signed tokens? You could basically encrypt the token with the client's (or user's) private key and then encrypt the package along with plaintext userid again with the server's public key. That way only the server can decrypt the package and once decrypted, it knows who the user is. It can then use the public key associated with that userid to decrypt to the package and get the token.

As you havent provided much info on the application and the speed of authentication required or technologies you are using, it is difficult to provide any more info.

Comment: Thank you for response! I was also considering such tokens but I postponed it as I don't want to bother with its implemention for now. My question is more focused on that API design whether that approach is OK or not and under which conditions.